# What are good German language programs for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: resource, software

There are a number of applications relating to introductory German, dictionaries etc. available on the app store. Have people had any success with any of them and which ones are worth trying?

Specifically I am interested in a full course (like Rosetta Stone), rather than just applications for memorizing words.

Comment: Related [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4970/audio-ausspracheworterbuch-fur-offline-usage-fur-das-ipad) about "Audio Aussprachewörterbuch".

Comment: Is anyone able to find a English-Deutsch-English dictionary for iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 6):

Try [Babbel Mobile](http://www.babbel.com/home/babbel-mobile):

- For iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad
- Access to 3000 words with sample sentences
- Interactive learning with sound and images
- Personal Vocabulary with Refresher Tool
- Switch anytime: Synchronization with Babbel.com
- Short and efficient units for practice in your spare time
- Available in seven languages
- Functions on- and offline

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try it myself (yet):

[**CanooNet Mobile**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canoonet/id294330973?mt=8)

From the app's description:

> - German dictionary, grammar reference, and spelling aid combined in a single app
> - offline Mode: CanooNet works without network access
> - fast and powerful search engine
> - convenient search and browse history
> - direct access to LEO translations and Wikipedia articles

You can try it for free (20 searches), the full version costs 15 Euro. The download is around 600 MB.

Comment: Bought the full version when it was reduced 50%. It's quite good and includes a lot of content from the website (not only the actual dictionary) in a form that is well-suited for a small display.

Comment: ...this is much simpler and much easier to use dictionary over Duden, Pons and Langenschaft iPad/iPhone dictionaries. But this does not have pronunciation --. I like the synonym-tree, Leo/Wikipedia redirection and integration of rules close to words (unlike with other apps). +1

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this new program for iPad and iPhone: http://www.learngerman.ch 
About 3'000 words for level B1 and B2.

Answer (score 1):

Apart form the apps Gigili and Splattne suggested I also discovered:

Busuu: This is a course based format. You can try it for free, but you must pay for the more advanced lessons.

Rosetta Stone: If you buy Rosetta Stone, you get access to the iPad app. This is a fairly expensive option, but its the full Rosetta stone experience on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I have created [an iOS app](http://duuro.com/derdiedas) that helps you learn more than 1000 German nouns for free.

We all know how hard it is to learn *der, die, das*, so I have created an app that makes you learn by playing.

Learning German nouns has never been so easy. [Try it by yourself, for free](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/learn-german-nouns-der-die-das/id646652757?ls=1&mt=8).

Answer (score -2):

I use [Fluenz](http://www.fluenz.com) for iOS and it's great. You can stream the lessons or download them for offline use.

Comment: welcome to german.stackexchange! maybe you could elaborate a bit more what the strong/weak points are and why you like it

Comment: See also [How to not be a spammer](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).