# Englisch-Deutsch-Englisch Wörterbuch für “offline usage” für das iPad oder iPhone?

Tags: resource, dictionary, software

Ich mag das [CanooNet Wörterbuch](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2069/887) und die [Aussprachewörterbücher](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4970/audio-ausspracheworterbuch-fur-offline-usage-fur-das-ipad) aber ich brauche auch ein Englisch-Deutsch-Englisch Wörterbuch für mein iPad/iPhone. Ich benutze jetzt zwar [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/pages.ende/iphone_en.html?lp=ende&lang=en) aber es geht nicht ohne Internet. Gibt es etwas ähnliches für das iPad/iPhone?

Übersicht [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4972/887).

Comment: [Steak](http://www.lotfi-tabrizi.de/steak/steak.html) ist ein freies Programm welches auf veschiedenen unixoiden Systemen läuft. Ob auf dem iPad/Phone weiss ich nicht. Das beiliegende Wörterbuch ist jedenfalls auch frei, so dass man sich leicht etwas eigenes dazu bauen kann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [UltraLingua iOS App](http://www.ultralingua.com/ultralingua-ios) on my iPod Touch, and am very happy with it. I believe the actual dictionary content comes from Collins and is very good (the best German-English dictionary you can get either paper or electronic, as far as I know), it has a *lot* of words in it, full conjugations of verbs, genders and plural forms of nouns, example phrases, etc. The app itself is simple and attractive, you can search for any form of a verb (even a misspelling) and it will find the infinitive, it has history and favourites, etc.

Comment: UltraLingua and Linguadict look the best quality apps -- UltraLingua much more expensive. Have you tried the cheaper Linguadict and how does it compare with UltraLingua?

Comment: I haven't tried Linguadict, but it doesn't look like it's in the same league as UltraLingua. Both the UltraLingua app itself and the German-English dictionary contents it comes with are _very_ good, worth the money if you're serious I think

Comment: Das ist richtig, danke +1.

Answer (score 2):

Da ich selbst keine Appleprodukte verwende, konnte ich die folgenden für Apple erhältlichen Wörterbücher nicht selbst testen:

- [German English Dictionary by Cole Zhu](https://itunes.apple.com/app/german-english-dictionary/id296851311?mt=8#)
- [Linguadict](http://www.linguatecapps.com/images/reviews/apptick_ld.pdf)
- [„Deutsch-Englisch Wörterbuch“ von bab.la...](http://www.focus.de/digital/handy/iphone/tid-19771/apple-handy-deutsch-englisch-woerterbuch-offline-uebersetzer_aid_549732.html)
- [PONS](http://www.pons.de/englisch/apps-e-books/iphone_ipod_touch_ipad/)

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin sehr zufrieden mit der dict.cc-App. Es gibt eine kostenlose, werbefinanzierte, und eine Plus-Version. Es können außer englisch auch noch zahlreiche andere Sprachpakete heruntergeladen werden. Es gibt auch eine Sprachausgabe, die dann aber eine Internetverbindung voraussetzt. Die Übersetzung in beide Richtungen geht aber vollständig offline.